# new property to model in xcode results in NSLocalizedDescription - Could not serialize managed object

Tags: ios, swift2, github-mantle

```
@interface ModelClass : SCObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *scObjectID;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *videoUrlHLS;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *fileUrlDirect;

@implementation ModelClass

+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey
{
    return @{ Key(ModelClass, scObjectID) : @"MediaId",
              Key(ModelClass, title) : @"Title",
              Key(ModelClass, videoUrlHLS) : @"VideoUrlAppleHLS",
              Key(ModelClass, fileUrlDirect) : @"FileUrlS3Direct"
}
```

The fileUrlDirect property is the new property and the JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey was updated to translate json property to model property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *fileUrlDirect;
Key(ModelClass, fileUrlDirect) : @"FileUrlS3Direct"
```

When I run

```
[MTLManagedObjectAdapter managedObjectFromModel:instanceOfModelClass insertingIntoContext:context error:error];
```

I receive

```
[0] (null)  @"NSLocalizedDescription" : @"Could not serialize managed object"   
[1] (null)  @"NSLocalizedFailureReason" : @"No property by name \"fileUrlDirect\" exists on the entity."
```

I've debugged and confirmed that the instanceOfModelClass has the new property but I can't figure out why I'm getting this error

I'm new to ios development and I'm guessing there is more to wire up for this to work but I'm not sure what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing property with name `fileUrlDirect` in your core data entity that you are mapping `instanceOfModelClass` into.

Comment: Thanks. I finally noticed the xcdatamodeld file and that was exactly what I needed